# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imread'

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv

I'm getting a error when trying to run a simple python opencv program on my mac.

```
   import cv
   import numpy as np
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

   img =cv.imread('road.jpg',0)
   plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')
   plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
   plt.show()
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mohitpandrangi/Documents/hello.py", line 5, in <module>
img =cv.imread('road.jpg',0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imread'
```

Comment: Have you named the script you're working on `cv.py`? If so, your `import cv` is importing your own script, which doesn't include `imread`.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) `imread` is in module `cv2`, not `cv`.

Comment: I had my opencv library named as cv.py, cv.pyc and cv2.so, so renamed everything as cv2 and now it works fine.Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I had my opencv library named as cv.py, cv.pyc and cv2.so, so renamed everything as cv2 and now it works fine.Thanks anyway!

That is

- cv2.py
- cv2.pyc

Comment: `cv2.so` is already a python module, and can be imported as is. The renaming you have done is unnecessary and counterproductive.